# Initialize struct in class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

How can we initailize a struct pointer in constructor of a class.
Example:

```
struct my_struct{
    int i; 
    char* name;
}; 
class my_class{ 
    my_struct* s1;
    my_class() {
        // here i want to make s1->i = 10; and s1->name = "anyname" ;  
        // should i assign it like s1->i= 10; and call new for s1->name and strcpy(s1->name "anyname");  
        // it compiles in g++ without any warning/error but gives seg fault at run time  
    }
};
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
 my_class() {
     s1 = new (my_struct);
     s1->i = 10;
     s1->name = (char *) malloc(strlen("anyname"));
     s1->name = "anyname";
     // here i want to make s1->i = 10; and s1->name = "anyname" ;  
     // should i assign it like s1->i= 10; and call new for s1->name and strcpy(s1->name "anyname");  
     // it compiles in g++ without any warning/error but gives seg fault at run time  
  }


 ~my_class(){
     free(s1->name);
     delete s1;
  }
```

Comment: at least you've considered `name`'s storage - some of the other answers here haven't...

Comment: The code is wrong. If `s->name` is of type `char *`, assigning its value with the line `s1->name = "anyname";` is the wrong way to do it, and after that, I doubt the execution will proceed without crash at the line `free(s1->name);`. The right way to do it is to use a `strpcy` or one of its variants.

Comment: most probably this should be `s1->name = strdup( ... );`.

Answer (score 17):

I'm surprised that no-one has suggested the following...

```
struct my_struct
{
  int i; 
  std::string name;

  my_struct(int argI, std::string const& argName) : i(argI), name(argName) {}
};

class my_class
{
  my_struct s1;  // no need for pointers!

  my_class() : s1(1, std::string("test name")) {} // construct s1 using the two argument constructor, can also default construct as well.
};
```

With this approach, you don't need to worry about cleaning up `s1`, it's automatic...

Comment: +1. `I'm surprised that no-one has suggested the following...` Indeed... I'm shocked at how much mallocs/news I see in those answers. :-/

Answer (score 3):

When you create an instance of `my_class`, the `s1` pointer doesn't point to anything. You have to allocate memory for it like so:

```
myclass() {
    s1 = new my_struct;
    // initialize variables
}
```

You will also have to create a destructor for it:

```
~myclass() {
    // delete variables
    delete s1;
}
```

Also, since this is C++, I recommend you use `std::string` instead of `char*`s.

Comment: Or better yet, change the definition of `s1` to `std::auto_ptr<my_struct> s1` or `std::unique_ptr<my_struct> s1`. No need to delete it in the destructor then.

Comment: @Vishal : Ok, but not all compilers offer access to C++11. For these compilers, `std::auto_ptr` remains a valid solution, if a limited one.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is C++, use `std::string` instead of `char*`:

```
struct my_struct{
    int i; 
    std::string name;
}; 
class my_class{ 
    my_struct* s1;
    my_class() {
        s1 = new my_struct;
        s1->i = 10;
        s1->name = "anyname";
    }
};
```

The reason your original code segfaulted was that you failed to allocate memory for `s1` and also failed to allocate memory for `s1->name`. I've fixed the former with the `new` and the latter by using `std::string`. If for some reason you can't use `std::string`, use `strdup` where you were trying to use `strcpy`.

Lastly, don't forget to provide a destructor for `my_class` that'll delete `s1` (and will free `s1->name` if you opt for `char*` and `strdup`).

Comment: Remember to delete the `s1` pointer in the destructor (if it must be a raw pointer).

Comment: Thanks aix...i got it :).. but still I am not convinced why not to use char* in c++.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `std::string`. But why stop here? I would also change `my_struct*` to `std::unique_ptr<my_struct>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use an initialization list, and new+init the struct directly. Also, you can't forget that you have to delete the pointer when you're done:

```
struct my_struct{
    int i; 
    char* name;
}; 
class my_class{ 
    my_struct* s1;
    my_class() : s1(new my_struct) {
        s1->i = 2;
        s1->name = "Something";
    }
    ~my_class() { delete s1; }
};
```

Also, make sure you're using a `char*` for a reason, otherwise a `std::string` will most often be better.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is inside the class, you can use the structure constructor:

```
struct my_struct
{
  int i; 
  std::string name;

  my_struct()
  {
    i = 10;
    name = "anyname";
  };
};
```

If it's global, you first need to create the object and then initialize it:

```
class my_class
{ 
  my_struct * s1;
  my_class() : s1(new my_struct())
  {
    s1->i = 10;
    s1->name = "anyname";
  }
};
```